# Convertir array asociativo en colección

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero convertir este array asociativo de nuevo en colección para generar el pdf:

```
$articulos = $request->get('articulos')
```

Esta es la función a la que habría que añadir la conversión:

```
public function informe(Request $request)
{
    $filtro = $request->get('filtro');
    $articulos = $request->get('articulos');
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('articulos.informe', compact('articulos'));
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Por otro lado, sólo logro que me funcione si lo hago de esta forma, es decir, volviendo a hacer la consulta nuevamente:

```
public function informe(Request $request)
{
    $filtro = $request->get('filtro');
    $articulos = Articulo::where('DescripcionArticulo', 'like', "%$filtro%")->orderBy('CodigoArticulo')->get();
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('articulos.informe', compact('articulos'));
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

En resumen, no quiero hacer dos consultas, sino una y enviar los datos de una vista a otra pasando por el controlador.

Espero haberme explicado correctamente. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Pues no entiendo muy bien qué tratas de hacer. En Laravel solo debes hacer uso del helper [collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-collect)

Comment: Lo que intento es no hacer la consulta de nuevo, sólo pasar el resultado y mostrarlos en el pdf. He probado lo que me dices y me devuelve esto: array:1 ["onEachSide" => "3"]

Comment: @SergioVS segun tu pregunta, la respuesta es `collect($articulos)`, como dice gaidyjg. Por lo otro que dices, edita y expica mejor ese detalle. ¿Request articulos es igua a `Articulo::where('....`?

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es almacenar el valor de tu consulta eloquent, que te devolvería un collect, guardarlo en una variable fuera del scope de funciones y luego la llamas dentro de donde lo necesites, pero me parece poco práctico.

Comment: Al final lo pude solventar con el uso de Session::flash('articulos', $articulos) para guardar la colección y $articulos = Session::get('articulos') para obtenerla en otro método del mismo controller. Gracias a todos por ayudar.